# Read a file into a list by a class does not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I wrote an android app with xamarin in c#, and I made an application class to manage the file with the data wich I want to load in a list.

The app class:

```
namespace soroksar_sc_stat
{
[Application]
public class GetDataClass : Android.App.Application
{

    public GetDataClass (){}

    private string filename = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"playerdata.txt");
    private DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
    private FileStream myFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"playerdata.txt"), FileMode.Create);

    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(this.myFile);
        string line;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        while((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            list.Add(line);
        }

        myReader.Close ();
        list.Add ("Blabla");
        return list;
    }

    public void SetNewData (string playerName, DateTime bornDate)
    {

        string newLine = playerName + " " + bornDate.ToString () + " 0 0 0 0";
        StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(this.myFile);
        myWriter.WriteLine(newLine);
        myWriter.Close();

    }




}
}
```

The activity which should show the list

```
namespace soroksar_sc_stat
{
[Activity (Label = "DataActivity")]         
public class DataActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.DataLayout);

        Button addbutton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.dataButton);
        ListView lista = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);

        GetDataClass dataList = new GetDataClass();


        List<string> list = dataList.GetList();

        addbutton.Click += delegate 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(AddDataActivity));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
        };

        }

    }
}
```

The first one is the class for the reading. Now it is an empty file, but for the troubleshooting I added a string at the end of the reading. However if I start the emulator in the second activity (which code is the second one) the list does not have any item. I don't really know where the problem is, if someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: my guess is that you don't close the streamreader/writer correctly - either wrap the declaration in a `using block` or use `flush`

Comment: Thanky you, i tried a Using block, but it did not work. Could you help me, that how should I exactly use flush?

Comment: I attached an answer showing, both ways, if its not this then its a bit hard to tell from the code given, you may need to verify the line you are passing in contains data. Regardless, my advice would still be an improvement for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned previously in my comment, I think that because you aren't closing the streamreader correctly, it may be closing before ever writing to the file. The solution would be one of the following

```
public void SetNewData (string playerName, DateTime bornDate)
{

    string newLine = playerName + " " + bornDate.ToString () + " 0 0 0 0";
    using(StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(this.myFile))
        myWriter.WriteLine(newLine);
}
```

```
public void SetNewData (string playerName, DateTime bornDate)
{

    string newLine = playerName + " " + bornDate.ToString () + " 0 0 0 0";
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(this.myFile);
    myWriter.WriteLine(newLine);
    myWriter.Flush();
    myWriter.Close();
}
```

Please note: That the first way is my preferred way as it makes sure all cleanup is done correctly. Also you should use a using block for reading too

```
using(StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(this.myFile))
{
    string line;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    while((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not tested the write in the file part, but I did the exact same solution with the streamreader and before I returned the list I added a string to it, because now the file is empty. My problem is that in the activity when I call the class it returns an empty list. (I overwrite the streamwriter part too, still the same) Also I would like to thank for your help, I never used Using before, but now I know when could it come handy :)

Comment: @gepont - If I'm honest I didn't bother to look at the activity because I doubt that is the problem if there isn't any data in the file to begin with. Having a second look, it may because you don't close the `FileStream` in a similar way to what I have shown in the above examples